# How to use custom typeface for vertex labels in python igraph?

Tags: python, igraph

In R igraph, there is an easy way to set a custom typeface for vertex labels and other texts on graph plots:

```
plot(G,vertex.label.family="DINPro")
```

However as I see, `vertex_label_family` parameter is not available in python igraph. It took some time while I have found some workaround to be able to set the label font, so I will post my solution here. And I'm wondering, if there are more elegant or easier solutions. First I tried to call cairo's `context.select_font_face()` on the igraph plot object's context, but sadly the `draw()` function in `igraph.drawing.graph.DefaultGraphDrawer()` overwrites it in each `plot.redraw()`:

```
lo = graph.layout_fruchterman_reingold()
sf = cairo.PDFSurface("test.pdf",1280,1280)
bx = igraph.drawing.utils.BoundingBox(10, 10, 1260, 1260)
plot = igraph.plot(graph,layout=lo,target=sf,bbox=bx)
plot._ctx.select_font_face("DINPro", cairo.FONT_SLANT_NORMAL, cairo.FONT_WEIGHT_NORMAL)
plot.redraw()
plot.save()
```

So this doesn't work. I will post a simple solution what works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could manage to set the typeface of vertex labels with replacing the `DefaultGraphDrawer` class with a new one, which only differs in two lines from the original. I simply copied the `igraph/drawing/graph.py` file from the site-packages directory of my python distribution, and I deleted every other classes except the `DefaultDraphDrawer`. After the imports, I added a line to import the `AbstractCairoGraphDrawer`, and modified the `__all__[]` list:

```
from igraph.drawing.graph import AbstractCairoGraphDrawer
__all__ = ["DefaultGraphDrawerFFsupport"]
```

Then I renamed the `DefaultGraphDrawer` class, modified the font selection part of it:

```
class DefaultGraphDrawerFFsupport(AbstractCairoGraphDrawer):
    ...
    def draw(...):
        ...
        fontFamily = graph.font if hasattr(graph, "font") else "sans-serif"
        context.select_font_face(fontFamily, cairo.FONT_SLANT_NORMAL, \
             cairo.FONT_WEIGHT_NORMAL)
        ...
    ...
```

I put this file (`ig_drawing.py`) in the directory of my module, and imported it. The I could set any typeface by passing the modified class as `drawing_factory` parameter for the `plot()` function:

```
from ig_drawing import *
lo = graph.layout_fruchterman_reingold()
sf = cairo.PDFSurface("test.pdf",1280,1280)
bx = igraph.drawing.utils.BoundingBox(10, 10, 1260, 1260)
df = igraph.drawing.graph.DefaultGraphDrawer(ctx, bx)
graph.font = "DINPro"
plot = graph.plot(graph,layout=lo,target=sf,bbox=bx,vertex_label=graph.vs["label"],drawer_factory=DefaultGraphDrawerFFsupport)
a.plot.save()
```

In case you don't set the `graph.font`, it uses "sans-serif". But also if you give a non existing font name, then without error message it falls back to your system's default sans font.

It looks like the default "sans-serif" typeface is hardcoded in igraph, both in plotting functions using cairo surfaces and svg. Any simpler way to change this?

Comment: You are right, unfortunately the `sans-serif` font face is currently hardcoded into `DefaultGraphDrawer`. I wanted to fix this for quite a while now, but doing it "properly" would mean to move all the label drawing code in `DefaultGraphDrawer` into `AbstractVertexDrawer` (because IMHO this is where it belongs logically), and I never really found spare time for it. Yours is a nice workaround and I couldn't think of anything simpler for the time being. Let me know if you are interested in tidying up your code a bit so it could get included in the next release.

Comment: @Tamás: Thank you for your reply! Yes, it would be nice to include this in the oncoming release. I also have one other idea what could be included in igraph, I'm open to talk about it, and to contribute if it's possible.